# Javascript error in Bokeh Nested Categorical Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm creating a nested categorical bar chart with bokeh and pandas. I tested the exampled included in Bokeh docs (shown below)

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg_clean as df
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("bar_pandas_groupby_nested.html")

df.cyl = df.cyl.astype(str)
df.yr = df.yr.astype(str)

group = df.groupby(by=['cyl', 'mfr'])

index_cmap = factor_cmap('cyl_mfr', palette=Spectral5, factors=sorted(df.cyl.unique()), end=1)

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, title="Mean MPG by # Cylinders and Manufacturer",
           x_range=group, toolbar_location=None, tooltips=[("MPG", "@mpg_mean"), ("Cyl, Mfr", "@cyl_mfr")])

p.vbar(x='cyl_mfr', top='mpg_mean', width=1, source=group,
       line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, )

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.05
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Manufacturer grouped by # Cylinders"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

I'm trying to apply this with my out set of data. However, we i run the script i get the error

[Js error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT9DP.png)

This is my code:

```
def test(data):
    output_file("bar_pandas_groupby_nested.html")
    print(df.head())
    data.prueba = data.prueba.astype(str)
    data.inst_nombre_institucion = data.inst_nombre_institucion.astype(str)

    group = data.groupby(by=['prueba', 'inst_nombre_institucion'])

    index_cmap = factor_cmap('prueba_inst_nombre_institucion', palette=Spectral5, factors=sorted(data.prueba.unique()), end=1)

    p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, title="Mean",
               x_range=group, toolbar_location=None, tooltips=[("MPG", "@media_mod_ingles_mean"), ("prueba, institucion", "@prueba_inst_nombre_institucion")])

    p.vbar(x='prueba_inst_nombre_institucion', top='media_mod_ingles_mean', width=1, source=group,
           line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, )

    p.y_range.start = 0
    p.x_range.range_padding = 0.05
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    p.xaxis.axis_label = "Mean"
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
    p.outline_line_color = None

    show(p)
    return True
```

And my data looks like this:
[data.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdeHD.png)

Why do i get this error?

Thanks for your time!

UPDATE:

data.csv and script can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_Ozpll8J1HtPnzsGZAkX-MxpEzSddTkA)

Comment: Of all the errors I might have expected to see, a layout error is not anywhere on the list. I'd like to investigate this directly, can you provide a compete script and data file to run?

Comment: @bigreddot Here is the data and script requested. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_Ozpll8J1HtPnzsGZAkX-MxpEzSddTkA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your labels are *way*, ***way*** too long to fit inside a 300px high plot when they are oriented vertical-ish. If I change the orientation to

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0.2
```

Then the plot can render, but you can also see the problem:

[image]

Alternatively, if I make the labels actually nearly vertical (~pi/2), and make the plot height be 800px, everything is visible:

[image]

But I would say that still is fairly hard to interpret/read. I would suggest trying to find shorter strings to use for your categories.

Comment: Thank you! I've tested changing the orientation of the labels and the chart renders properly. I'll need to trim the labels.